# Datepicker not clickable in mobile device

Tags: angular, datepicker

I changed the html location of the datepicker in the same div and after that the Angular datepicker is not clickable in mobile version, hence not working. It worked in mobile version before that. Any idea what could have gone wrong or where to even start looking?

/Added the code I have for this./

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label style="color:white;">Date</label>
    <datepicker date-format="d MMMM, yyyy">
        <input ng-class="{true: 'error-bron', false:'nonerror-bron'}[dateError===true]" readonly="true" class="bron-date" ng-model="$root.date" type="text" placeholder="Pick a date"/>
    </datepicker>
</div>
```

And CSS part:

```
.bron-date  {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 21px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


datepicker, .datepicker, [datepicker],
._720kb-datepicker-calendar-header,
._720kb-datepicker-calendar-body,
._720kb-datepicker-calendar-days-header,
._720kb-datepicker-calendar-years-pagination-pages {
font-family: spaceMono;
font-size: 13.5px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;
clear: right;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
```

Solved it.

Basically in the mobile view the lower div was covering up the datepicker div so it wasnt possible to click it. So when I told the program that in the mobile view this div should take up the whole width of the screen it didnt go all messed up and the datepicker was not "covered" hence it was clickable.

Comment: You should explain the answer for others, code only answers are discouraged, even in simple cases like this.

Comment: Basically in the mobile view the lower div was covering up the datepicker div so it wasnt possible to click it. So when I told the program that in the mobile view this div should take up the whole width of the screen it didnt go all messed up and the datepicker was not "covered" hence it was clickable.

Comment: I've added that comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with website (html) on mobile device, cause they don't use real mouse, you need to add this to the datepicker element in css :

```
datepicker {

 cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: I added the the pointer here but it still will not open. Also added my code part.

Comment: Also I tried to change the divs back. And then it works in the mobile version. But I need the datepicker to be between the two divs